# Google Docs API create an empty document

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-developers-console

I try now to create a document with Ggoogle Docs APIwith my content, but every time i create it, it will be embty, what should i do to fix the problem?

I use the same code from google example to do this.
[link to example](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22body%22%3A%7B%22content%22%3A%5B%7B%22endIndex%22%3A1%2C%22sectionBreak%22%3A%7B%22sectionStyle%22%3A%7B%22columnSeparatorStyle%22%3A%22NONE%22%2C%22contentDirection%22%3A%22LEFT_TO_RIGHT%22%2C%22sectionType%22%3A%22CONTINUOUS%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22startIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endIndex%22%3A55%2C%22paragraph%22%3A%7B%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22startIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endIndex%22%3A55%2C%22textRun%22%3A%7B%22content%22%3A%22testst%20atesatset%20as%20dasfdas%20dfasdf%20asdf%20asdf%20asdf%20asd%5Cn%22%2C%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22paragraphStyle%22%3A%7B%22namedStyleType%22%3A%22NORMAL_TEXT%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22LEFT_TO_RIGHT%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D)

My Content example:

```
      {
        "title": "testitesti",
        "body": {
          "content": [
            {
              "endIndex": 1,
              "sectionBreak": {
                "sectionStyle": {
                  "columnSeparatorStyle": "NONE",
                  "contentDirection": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                  "sectionType": "CONTINUOUS"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "startIndex": 1,
              "endIndex": 6,
              "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "startIndex": 1,
                    "endIndex": 6,
                    "textRun": {
                      "content": "test\n",
                      "textStyle": {}
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                  "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                  "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) will always create blank documents:

> Creates a blank document using the title given in the request. **Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored**.

If you want to add content to your document using [document resource](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) properties, use [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

Comment: Correct, but, batchupdate takes different kind of Requests and document response contains different object(StructuralElement, Paragraph). What if I want to copy content from multiple docs in to another new doc or append multiple docs?